# How long between the final battle and the epilogue chapter in Golden Enclaves

Tags: scholomance

The final section of the Golden Enclaves wraps up with El, Her school mates and her Dad's family solving the need for malia based enclaves through some tweaks to the Golden Enclave spells and the introduction of a spell dancing method of performing the final casting.

How long does this take? It appears to happen off page and very quickly.

Comment: If I recall, the main insight was that multiple people could do the spells together if they all were strict mana. That seems like a minor innovation to the basic spell.

Comment: Also, as a side note, one of the interesting things about the series is that there is in reality *no* need for enclaves built on malia. They build enclaves because their children need to be protected from minor maleficaria that are too numerous to keep track of or defend against, as well as maw-mouths. The minor maleficaria are implied to largely exist because of the casual use of malia for unrelated tasks, and the maw-mouths exist because of the enclaves. If everyone just got together and agreed on everything, they could exterminate most minor mals and avoid creating more.

Comment: And the maw-mouths only exist because people rejected the golden enclave spells and killed their own in the pursuit of more space. Even the fact that their magic works worse out in the world at large is because they hid in enclaves long enough for a general lack of knowledge to develop. That's the tragedy of the whole series: an entire society hiding and living on a knife's edge for *wholly avoidable* reasons.

Comment: @Adamant The real problem with the malia based foundations is the awful secrecy vow that comes with it. Not only does it compel those who learn about the spell to secrecy, but they also must actively work to protect that secret. This creates a self-perpetuating cycle and a problem for which there is no true solution.

Comment: @Donald.McLean - I can't agree. The spell  only prevents people from learning what creates new maw-mouths, without obligating anyone to use it once it is sold to them. People do *that* because they value more enclave space and are willing to sacrifice a few lives to get it. Everyone who has chosen to build an enclave on a maw-mouth, from the first person to make the spell up until the present day, has chosen to sacrifice a people's lives for a larger enclave. That's avoidable.

Comment: But the larger point is much bigger than maw-mouths, which after all, despite being virtually unkillable, are by far *most* dangerous to people in closed-off spaces like enclaves and are quite rare. It's that they only need any enclaves in the first place because of *everyday misuse of malia*. It's easy to miss this because it is stated in a very different context, but the only reason there are even close to enough minor maleficaria to pose a threat to children is because *almost everyone cheats and uses minor malia for everyday things*. They are making the rope to hang themselves.

Comment: @Adamant I thought Ophelia made that point pretty explicitly. It was exactly what she wanted to solve by making everyone do things her way. Because Malia doesn't create the mal right her and now people do it because it's easier and everyone else is doing it so they rationalise there will be mals anyway.

Comment: @Adamant there's also a sunk cost problem. They new enclave creator has spent decades of mana to get the maw-mouth spells. At that point they will feel commited and obligated to those that don't know the cost. The sellers are the real problem here. And it isn't rejection of the Golden Enclaves it is inability to cast that is the initial problem. Hence the question about the quick solution to a 2000 year old problem.

Comment: @Jontia - I mean, I'd say *anyone* who is willing to condemn several people—often from their very own enclave, no less!—to eternal torture is definitely a real problem, or part of one. In any case, my impression, based on the bit about a text suggesting that people had rejected the golden enclave spells as primitive, was that at some point in the past people knew very well how to have multiple strict-mana people cast the golden enclave spells, but that when the maw-mouth method came along, since it did not require strict mana and allowed for more space, people jumped on that bandwagon.

Comment: It's basically an elaborate environmentalist metaphor, really. People take small actions that make their lives more convenient, but ultimately pollute the world for their children, even though they could get things done more slowly (but done nonetheless) with their own muscle power. They build their cities on the deaths of the unwanted, having rejected traditional construction techniques in favor of large, flashy, environmentally damaging houses, and then dump the externalities on the rest of the world. It is not terribly subtle.

Comment: @Adamant And done first (and IMO more poignantly) by Ursula K. LeGuin in "The Ones Who Walk Away from Omelas".

Comment: @Spencer - There are thematic similarities, granted, but Le Guin's short story is more of an exploration of the philosophical idea of the scapegoat, whereas Novik's story is plainly an allegory of pollution and modernization.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Over a month

First of all, it's not technically an epilogue chapter, just a normal chapter. Second, while they "solve" the problem, they don't actually do it in the book, it's only presented as the plan for what they will do. All that said, there is a fair bit of intervening time between the end of the penultimate chapter and the last chapter.

1. It says in the book that they spent all month in London Enclave working on casting diagrams and incantations for the foundation stones for golden stone enclaves.
2. It says that while they have figured out the spell, convincing enclaves to switch to them was problematic (as other enclaves are actively opposing them as they are under compulsion spells).
3. She only says in the book that the plan is for her to go hunting Maw Mouths (destroying the corresponding enclaves), and approaching those enclaves afterward to  help them rebuild them with golden foundations.

Comment: (3) is not quite correct. The plan is that her grandmother (?) the famous prophetess will inform the enclave that it is about to be attacked, and a new, golden enclave, foundation will be laid - and THEN El will destroy the Maw Mouth. This way, no enclaves will be affected, but the Maw Mouths will still be destroyed.